# hot analyze speech sample sent to google STT

Tags: speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech

I am looking for recording option in Google STT API. I want to listen to voice received by Google Speech API. What is the way to access stream received by API?
I also tried Wireshark on the server which is using streamingRecognize , but I do not know how to filter the speech packets sent

Comment: Streaming recognition results in a section of audio, while the final recognition represents all. This Function in Speech-to-text API does not let you listen to the streamed audio. However what you can do in your backend is to add a function to record the streamed voice and send it to a storage bucket.

Comment: this is not the same - I would like to ensure that packet I sent, received on API end point properly. And in case of issues I can see that was package loss for example. I need it for troubleshooting purpose

Comment: You can check the response for error messages if the results returned by Speech-to-text are not what you expected. Additionally i leave you the documentation of the troubleshooting guide for Speech-to-text API[1].
[1]https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/troubleshooting